# не удается выполнить команду prisma db push в nest js

Tags: nestjs, prisma

в `.env` создал переменную для подключения к бд `postgresql://user:password@45.117.25.64/authdb?schema=public`

при выполнении `prisma db push` выводится такая ошибка

> Error: P1013: The provided database string is invalid. invalid port number in database URL. Please refer to the documentation in https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/database-reference/connection-urls for constructing a correct connection string. In some cases, certain characters must be escaped. Please check the string for any illegal characters.